# Capistrano Capifony Github Deploy Windows

Tags: github, capistrano, rsync

I'm sure this has been asked a hundred times but I couldn't find anything on google or SE that pointed me to an acceptable answer.  I'm doing dev on a local windows 7 machine and have git 1.7.7.1 with Capistrano 2.9.0 installed and Capifony (downloaded yesterday).  When I attempt to do a deploy from github I get the following error:

`Command git ls-remote git@github.com:gituser/MyRepo.git master returned status code pid 6572 exit 1`

Here is my current deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "app"
set :domain,      "app.mydomain.com"
set :deploy_to,   "/home/user/#{domain}"
set :use_sudo,    false

set :repository,  "git@github.com:gituser/MyRepo.git"
set :scm,         :git
set :user,        "user"

default_run_options[:pty] = true  # Must be set for the password prompt from git to work
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true


# Deploy from master branch by default
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
#set :deploy_via,  :copy
#set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migrations will run

set  :keep_releases,  3
```

When I run `cap deploy` it asks for my local github passkey phrase which I enter and then prompts me with a ssh password for the host app.mydomain.com.. then dies with the exit above.

To be honest I started just trying to use capifony to just do a rsync deploy straight from my local machine via :deploy_via :copy or :deploy_via :rsync_with_remote_cache but both seemed to die for different reasons one of which is described here (but the fix didn't work for me):

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37822

FWIW: cap deploy:check works fine as well as cap deploy:setup...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late. But i was digging under this issue as well.

Looking at it i would say that capifony don't and won't work soon on windows. Increasing the log level there is a lot of commands specific to Linux and bash shell like "export" / $(xxx) etc...

i woill give a try to cygwin